# Web API Request - Send back authentication request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I am using the new MVC 4 Beta Web API.  I want to add an `[Authorize]` attribute to the `Get` action in order to have the user authenticate themselves before getting data from the server.  I am using fiddler to test the action, but it is redirecting me to the Login Url that is defined in the web.config.  I am using `[System.Web.Http.Authorize]` to add the `[Authorize]` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this happening is because the Forms Authentication module hijacks the 401 HTTP status code returned by the Web API and redirects to the Login page. You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx) in which Phil Haack talks about how to configure ASP.NET to prevent it from doing this for AJAX requests. You could slightly modify his code so that it does this for all requests, or only for requests for your Api controllers.

Comment: after installing this solution through NuGet I was still sent to the Login Redirect Url, but instead of a 200 that shows the Login I was receiving an error saying it could not find the controller after the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

To get it working in my API I just removed the authentication section from web.config and wrote (well converted from my WCF WebApi code) a message handler. I've put what I did in to a [blog post](http://sixgun.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/asp-net-web-api-basic-authentication/).